# Layout flexbox: how to get the leaf nodes centered vertically and horizontally within the half-containers?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I want to have a quite simple layout in mind but I can't get it working

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="top-half">
        <div class="center-me-vertically-and-horizontally"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-half">
        <div class="center-me-vertically-and-horizontally"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

page-wrapper and top-half/bottom-half is quite easy achievable with flexbox (columns) but how to I get the leaf nodes centerer vertically and horizontally within the half-containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inbricate flex boxes:

```css
html, body, .page-wrapper {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
.page-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }
.top-half , .bottom-half {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
    align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px ; /* lets see them */
  }
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="top-half">
        <div class="center-me-vertically-and-horizontally">top</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-half">
        <div class="center-me-vertically-and-horizontally">bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A reference for flexbox'ing that gave me a lot of insight can be found at [Flexbox|Codrops CSS Reference](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/)